# chown: changing ownership of '' ": Input/output error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, kubernetes, alibaba-cloud

I have tried the database application for mysql and postgres too. When I use pv type as OSS, and deploy the application, pods goes in CrashbackLoopOff. The error which I am constantly getting is

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Input/output error
```

(For PostgreSQL I get the same error with `var/lib/postgresql/data`.)

The path which it is giving error is of container.The ways which I tried is, before uploading files to OSS I changed the ownership of files and folders from 999 to root and then uploaded to OSS.
But then also I am getting this error for every database.
Please give me solution for this as I am stuck from longer time.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly there are few things you can do:

1. Launch the db container as `root` and than `chown` the directory. In case of mysql if you still can't change it than try running `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` as `mysql:mysql` is the default ownership there.
2. Use `initContainer` in order to change the target folder to `/var/lib/mysql/`
3. Use `securityContext` for `containers`. For example:

```
containers:
- name: mysql
  image: <msql_image>
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
```

It should all also work for `postgresql`.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I already have tried all these solutions, but still its not working. Can you please suggest me other solution which can deploy the database application without error.

Comment: In that case it's probably purely related to Cloud specific PV type - OSS, as such problem does not persist with PV of local or localHost types.

Comment: I am using OSS for Alibaba Cloud. So is there problem of OSS with Alibaba?